# Where is the kubectl command get executed?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know where do we usually  execute kubectl command ?

Is it on master node or a different node, because i executed kubectl command from one of the EC2 instances in AWS and master and worker node was completely  different ( total 3 node = 1 master and 2 worker node).

And when we create cluster ,does that cluster lies in worker node or it includes master node too?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think your question is answerable. You run kubectl from where ever you want to run it from, usually your laptop or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kubectl` command itself is a command line utility that always executes locally however all it really does is issue commands against a Kubernetes server via its [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/)

Which Kubernetes server it acts against is determined by the local environment the command is run with. This is configured using a "kubeconfig" file which is is read from the KUBECONFIG environment variable (or defaults to the file in in $HOME/.kube/config). For more information see [Configuring Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters)